# Revert Pull Request in Github

Tags: github, git-revert

I merged a pull request accidentally in github but it needs some changes how can I revert the pull request in github to add those changes that I want.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the Pull Request page: https://github.com/your_org/your_repo/pulls
2. Click on "Closed"
   [image]
3. Select your PR
4. Click on "revert"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do would be to simply make a new PR with the changes you want to make, as no matter what you do, the "bad" PR will always be a part of the git history. That being said, follow Vertexwhan's answer if you really want to revert the merge, but keep in mind that you will not be able to re-merge the same branch later on.

Comment: In my situation, I did revert the merge, but now I _do_ want to re-merge the same branch later on. How do I proceed?

Comment: @user93114 you would need to revert the revert.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, revert pushed commit results in new commits that remove your code.
Then, you can't merge again the PR, these commits are already in master history so PR can't be merged again after revertion.
The solution I found and which doesn't force history : 
On master, on your local repo : 
`git revert -m 1 <merged PR commit-hash>` 
The -m 1 : "specifies the parent number (starting from 1) of the mainline and allows revert to reverse the change relative to the specified parent." Keep master history clear.
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert
Next, you can create a new branch from master like : `unrevert-<my-branch>`.
On this new branch you can use git cherry-pich to restore reverted commits : `git cherry-pick <commit-hash>`.
Then, you can merge your `unrevert-<my-branch>` on your PR branch.
After it, you can reopen your PR and your commits are again mergable on master. You can continue to work on your branch like nothing happens.

That doesn't need to detach HEAD which can be complicated to deal with